# power automate update item expression

Tags: power-automate

concat('REQ-', '2023-', padStart(triggerOutputs()?['headers']['x-ms-file-last-modified']?['value'], 7, '0'), '-ID')
Is it a valid expression in update item in power automate.I m expecting the result like (REQ2023000000001).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a full list of function available in Power Automate/Logic Apps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference

padStart is not one of them, that is why your expression is invalid.

In your case you might be able to try and use a formatnumber function with a Zero placeholder instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatnumber
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings